# How do I bind the Flutter openGLES with an Android TextureView?

Tags: android, flutter, opengl-es

I am currently in the process of developing a Flutter plugin that utilizes an Android TextureView to render a view. This rendering process relies on a shared native library (libRender.so).

On the Android side, I am adopting the [composition pattern](https://flutter-ko.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views) approach, wherein I return a TextureView. Once the surfaceTexture of the TextureView becomes available, I initialize EGLContext, EGLSurface, and related components. Subsequently, I trigger a method on the Flutter side through a channel. This method, in turn, invokes a native function from libRender.so (which utilizes openGLES) to carry out drawing on the surface. However, an exception is thrown during this process, indicating that the EGLContext hasn't been initialized yet.

I am seeking guidance on how to effectively establish a connection between the Android TextureView's rendering process and the native drawing method. Specifically, I want to ensure the proper association of the EGLContext between them.